# "%" is getting URI decoded while everyhting else not

Tags: javascript, uri, sapui5, uriencoding

I have a strange UI5 problem. I create a string from a control's binding context which looks like:

```
Entity('Element%3AInfo%2CID')
```

Just for info, it looks like this decoded: `Entity('Element:Info,ID')`

However, I get this String from the following method chain:

```
oItem.getBindingContext().getPath().substr(1)
```

So, the whole (pretty basic) "navigate to" block looks like this:

```
showElement : function (oItem) {
    'use strict';

    var bReplace = jQuery.device.is.phone ? false : true;

    sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this).navTo("element", {
        from: "master",
        element: oItem.getBindingContext().getPath().substr(1),
        otherpattern: "something"
    }, bReplace);
},
```

A console log in this block `console.log(oItem.getBindingContext().getPath().substr(1));` provides the right string.

> Console output of console.log(oItem.getBindingContext().getPath().substr(1)):
>   Entity('Element%3AInfo%2CID')

The problem is (be aware, this is getting curious) that my URL pattern "`{element}`" is filled with:

```
Entity('Element%253AInfo%252CID')
```

Decoded: `Entity('Element%3AInfo%2CID')`

As you probably already know, the pattern's "%" is encoded. I don't get why UI5 would do this.

You should also know these facts which I've tested:

- `decodeURIComponent(oItem.getBindingContext().getPath().substr(1))` leads to "`Entity('Element:Info,ID')`"
- `encodeURIComponent(oItem.getBindingContext().getPath().substr(1))` leads to "`Entity('Element%25253AInfo%25252CID')`"
- `oItem.getBindingContext().getPath().substr(1).replace("%3A", ":")` leads to "`Entity('Element:Info%252CID')`"

Is this a bug? I mean the URI pattern is left untouched as long as it doesn't come to a "%". *For some odd reason this special character is encoded while everything else doesn't matter.*

Comment: My intuition is that the library requires a decoded string.

Comment: @royhowie A fully decoded string (see the first list item) doesn't fit because I need the string like this Entity('Element%3AInfo%2CID')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not exactly like "%" is getting encoded and everything else is not encoded.

I also came across this issue. **SAPUI5** does encoding once, and **browser** does it second time. Hence in the second iteration you will have only "%" to be encoded.

Initial string : `Element:Info,ID`

after first iteration of encoding(by UI5 framework) `encodeURIComponent('Element:Info,ID')` : We get `Element%3AInfo%2CID`

So for the second iteration, only % is left to be encoded `Element%253AInfo%252CID` hence we get this.

So if you are picking up the binding context from URL, you need to decode twice.
Else as you are doing once is fine.